# リストからランダムにデータを取り出して新たなデータリストを作りたい

Tags: python, numpy

私は、下記のような100×3の行列リストを持っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この行列に対して行いたい処理は2つあります。

・ランダムに2つの行を抽出することを、任意の回数(例えば、3回)行いたい　
ex) [[a1, a2, a3],
[b1, b2, b3]]
・抽出した2つの行を1つの行になるように変更して、試行した回数×取り出した行の組という行列を作りたい
[[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3],
[c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3],
[e1, e2, e2, f1, f2, f3]]

追記　
最初の100×3の行列では、1行分の値、つまり、3つの値の数の塊として扱っています。

Comment: (100, 3) から (10, 6) の matrix という点がよく分かりませんが、[numpy.random.permutation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) を使って、`np.random.permutation(x)[0:20].reshape(10, 6)` など。

Comment: それは考えましたが、最初の行列の行を取り出した時の値、つまり3つの値はまとまって扱いたいです。ですので、その方法は断念してしまいました。

Comment: 例えば `x = np.array(range(300)).reshape(100,3)` としておいて、`np.random.permutation(x)[0:20].reshape(10, 6)` の結果をみると「3つの値」がまとまっていることが判るかと思います。

Comment: 制約があるのであれば質問に追記してください。

Comment: 「ランダムに取り出す」と「別の行列 (数) に変形する」は、分けて質問した方がよさそうです。

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

まず適当な行列

```
a = np.array([[m*3 + n for n in range(3)] for m in range(20)])
```

があった時

```
b = a[np.random.choice(a.shape[0], 8, replace=False), :]
```

でいけます。`a.shape[0]` で `a` の行サイズを取り出し `np.random.choice` でインデックスの乱数を作ります。`replace=False` が重複なしにするオプションです。これで `a[n,:]` という形で行を取り出すことが出来ます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
これだと作成した乱数の数の行×3の行列になります。
僕はそこからさらに、10×6という行列に変えるとこまで行いたいです。
そのためにはどうすればよろしいかも教えていただけると嬉しいです。
未熟で申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

答えてくれている人のを参考に逐次処理で書いたものです。
XとYを変えればある程度自由な値で作成できると思います。

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.array([[m*3 + n for n in range(3)] for m in range(100)])

# 任意の回数を決める
X = 10
# 抽出する行の個数を決める
Y = 2

ans = np.zeros((X,3*Y))
for i in range(X):
    ans_list = np.array([])
    for _ in range(Y):
        ans_list = np.append(ans_list,a[random.randrange(100)])
    ans[i] = ans_list

print(ans)
```