# リストからランダムに行を抽出し、新たな配列を配列を作りたい

Tags: python, numpy

私は、下記のような100×3の行列リストを持っています。
この行列に対して行いたい処理は2つあります。
・ランダムに2つの行を抽出することを、任意の回数(例えば、3回)行いたい　
ex) [[a1, a2, a3],
[b1, b2, b3]]
・抽出した2つの行を1つの行になるように変更して、試行した回数×取り出した行の組という行列を作りたい
[[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3],
[c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3],
[e1, e2, e2, f1, f2, f3]]

追記　
最初の100×3の行列では、1行分の値、つまり、3つの値の数の塊として扱っています。

Comment: これを参考にしましたが、うまくいかず質問しました。

Comment: 前の記事の metropolis さんコメントの内容で問題なく動作するように思えるのですが、何が如何上手くいかなかったのか結果の詳細を追記すると的確な助言や回答が得られるかもしれません。今回の payaneco さんの回答で問題無ければ、それはそれで解決かもしれませんが。

Comment: @kunif さんのコメントと多少重複しますが…。上記のご質問と本文が同一なので「ランダムに取り出す」と「別の行列 (数) に変形する」のどちらにフォーカスした質問かを読み解くことが困難です。また`ex)`に記述されている出力からランダム性を見いだせません。質問をコピーするのではなく「困っていること」と「望んでいるゴール」を明示されますようにそれぞれの質問をご編集いただくと、より的確な回答が集まるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

下記のサンプルコードでお望みの操作を達成できるでしょうか。
配列をランダムに並べ替えた後に先頭から任意個のペアを取得し、配列を`+`演算子で結合することができます。

[別のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73047)への @metropolis さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73047/%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%80%e3%83%a0%e3%81%ab%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e6%96%b0%e3%81%9f%e3%81%aa%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment81130_73047)の方がエレガントに同様の結果を出せるのでサンプルコードに追記しました。

```
import string
import random

# 下準備として ["a1", "a2", "a3"] から ["z1", "z2", "z3"] までの配列を作る
arr = []
for c in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    arr.append([f"{c}{i}" for i in range(1, 4)])

# ランダムに任意個の行を抽出する(3個)
count = 3
random.shuffle(arr) # 完全にランダムなシャッフルを行う
rnd_arr = []
for i in range(0, count * 2, 2): # 先頭から2つの行を任意個取り出す
    rnd_arr.append(arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) # 2つの行を1つの配列にまとめる
print(rnd_arr)
# [['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3']] など

# 追記(numpy版)
import numpy as np
rnd_nparr = np.random.permutation(arr)[0:count*2].reshape(3, 6)
print(rnd_nparr)
# [['r1' 'r2' 'r3' 'e1' 'e2' 'e3']
#  ['x1' 'x2' 'x3' 's1' 's2' 's3']
#  ['m1' 'm2' 'm3' 'b1' 'b2' 'b3']] など
```